# list all #region in the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I like the regions feature in Visual Studio.

However,　I wonder is there a UI to list all #region/#endregion blocks so that users can easily navigate between them?

Comment: Not a UI, but you surely can find them by searching for "#region" through the search box (*Ctrl + F*).

Comment: There are various functions in Edit -> Outlining which might help you. E.g. "Collapse to definitions" (Ctrl+M, O)

Comment: I am hoping to see something similar to the class/function navigation bar. I believe it should be convenient.

Comment: Just have smaller classes and use the solution explorer to navigate between them.  If you have much more than a couple of hundred lines in a file, it's usually worth breaking it into chunks.

Answer (score 3):

I just learned that Visual Assist X provides such region listing function in the form of navigation bar.

I need some time to try it out though.

[image: region list]